# Difference between dates in two consecutive rows

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

```
+----------+--------------+-------------------------+
| ticketid | ticketpostid |           date          |
+----------+--------------+-------------------------+
|  1387935 |      3147808 | 2012-09-17 13:33:01     |
|  1387935 |      3147812 | 2012-09-17 13:33:41     |
|  1387938 |      3147818 | 2012-09-17 13:35:01     |
|  1387938 |      3148068 | 2012-09-17 13:37:01     |
|  1387938 |      3148323 | 2012-09-17 14:47:01     |
|  1387939 |      3147820 | 2012-09-17 13:36:01     |
|  1387939 |      3147834 | 2012-09-17 13:36:25     |
|  1387939 |      3147851 | 2012-09-17 13:41:01     |
|  1387939 |      3147968 | 2012-09-17 13:59:06     |
|  1387939 |      3147996 | 2012-09-17 14:03:01     |
```

This is a result of a query that I wrote. There are two and more than two rows with same ticketid. I need to find the time difference between first two date in each ticketid

Ex.

```
+----------+--------------+-------------------------+
| ticketid | ticketpostid |           date          |
+----------+--------------+-------------------------+
|  1387935 |      3147808 | 2012-09-17 13:33:01     |
|  1387935 |      3147812 | 2012-09-17 13:33:41     |
|  1387938 |      3147818 | 2012-09-17 13:35:01     |
|  1387938 |      3148068 | 2012-09-17 13:37:01     |
|  1387939 |      3147820 | 2012-09-17 13:36:01     |
|  1387939 |      3147834 | 2012-09-17 13:36:25     |
```

As a result;

```
+----------+--------------+
| ticketid |time diff(sec)|
+----------+--------------+
|  1387935 |      40      |
|  1387938 |      120     |
|  1387939 |      24      |
```

Can you tell me how I can do this?

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the data and expected result. It's great if you show this in `INSERT` form so it's easy to create as a sample, but this works. BTW, which PostgreSQL version?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

For PostgreSQL, I think you want the [`lag` window function](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-window.html) to compare the rows; it'll be much more efficient than a self-join and filter. This won't work with MySQL, as it still doesn't seem to support the standard SQL:2003 window functions; see below.

To find only the two lowest you can use the `dense_rank` window function over the `ticketid`, then filter the results to return only rows where `dense_rank() = 2`, ie row with the second-from-lowest timestamp, where `lag()` will produce the row with the lowest timestamp.

See [this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/0e213/1)  which shows sample DDL and output.

```
SELECT ticketid, extract(epoch from tdiff) FROM (
  SELECT
      ticketid,
      ticketdate - lag(ticketdate) OVER (PARTITION BY ticketid ORDER BY ticketdate) AS tdiff,
      dense_rank() OVER (PARTITION BY ticketid ORDER BY ticketdate) AS rank
  FROM Table1
  ORDER BY ticketid) x
WHERE rank = 2;
```

I've used `ticketdate` as the name for the date column because `date` is a terrible name for a column (it's a data type name) and should never be used; it has to be double quoted in many situations to work.

The portable approach is probably the self-join others have posted. The window function approach above probably works on Oracle too, but doesn't seem to in MySQL. As far as I can find out it doesn't support the SQL:2003 window functions.

The schema definition will work with MySQL if you `SET sql_mode = 'ANSI'` and use `timestamp` instead of `timestamp with time zone`. It seems the window functions won't; MySQL chokes on the `OVER` clause. See [this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/846e8/1).

Answer (score 2):

Try this query -

```
INSERT INTO ticket_post(ticketid, ticketpostid, date) VALUES
(1387935, 3147808, '2012-09-17 13:33:01'),
(1387935, 3147812, '2012-09-17 13:33:41'),
(1387938, 3147818, '2012-09-17 13:35:01'),
(1387938, 3148068, '2012-09-17 13:37:01'),
(1387938, 3148323, '2012-09-17 14:47:01'),
(1387939, 3147820, '2012-09-17 13:36:01'),
(1387939, 3147834, '2012-09-17 13:36:25'),
(1387939, 3147851, '2012-09-17 13:41:01'),
(1387939, 3147968, '2012-09-17 13:59:06'),
(1387939, 3147996, '2012-09-17 14:03:01');

SELECT
  ticketid,
  TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF((
    SELECT t.date FROM ticket_post t WHERE t.ticketid = t1.ticketid AND t.date > t1.date ORDER BY t.date LIMIT 1),
    MIN(date)
  )) diff FROM ticket_post t1
GROUP BY ticketid;

+----------+------+
| ticketid | diff |
+----------+------+
|  1387935 |   40 |
|  1387938 |  120 |
|  1387939 |   24 |
+----------+------+
```

Comment: I get different results and i'm a bit confused. Can you show your schema and sample data? Compare: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/846e8/6

Comment: Ah. There are two sample data sets there. I used the top one, you used the other. That explains it. My mistake. BTW, worth noting in your answer that it's MySQL only.

Answer (score 1):

```
select 
  ticketid
  ,time_to_sec(timediff(t2.date, t1.date))  as timediff
from table t1
join table t2 on t1.ticketid=t2.ticketid and t1.ticketpostid<t2.ticketpostid
```

Comment: I think this approach is valid, however, it will return extra rows when there are more than 2 of the same ticketids.  It would compare ticket1 to ticket2, ticket2 to ticket3, but also ticket1 to ticket3, which isn't desired.

Comment: True, but the sql is done regarding the problem's data. It is easily modified to take in consideration 1st and 2nd, or 1st and last or whatever. It is done for 2 :) .