# time between same id ticketing system

Tags: mysql, select, time

I'm using a ticketing system, and need to write a query to check if the agents are they late with their delivery.

This is what I have up to now and what I need:

- I have: `ticket_id   time_created`
- I need to select all same ticket_id where time_created between the two of them is
  greater then 24 hours.

For example:

```
ticket_id time_created 
1         2013-08-19 12:11
1         2013-08-17 12:07
1         2013-08-17 12:00
2         2013-08-19 12:11
2         2013-08-19 12:10
```

The result

```
ticket_id time_difference
1             48:04
```

I only need to check tickets with same ticket_id number.

EDIT
lets say there is and id column too
i need check values between 1,2 then 2,3 (in this case - all ticket_id=1)
and 4,5 (ticket_id=2)

Comment: Please post the SQL that you have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This query would check the difference between the last date and lowest date, do you want this or the difference between the last date and the second last date

```
SELECT ticket_id, 
DATEDIFF(MAX(TIME_CREATED),MIN(TIME_CREATED)) AS DiffDate 
FROM TABLE1 
    group by ticket_id
```

This query should find the difference between the two latest tickets

```
SELECT ticket_id, TIMEDIFF(MAX(A.TIME_CREATED),

             (SELECT MAX(TIME_CREATED) FROM TICKETS B 
              where B.TIME_CREATED <MAX(A.TIME_CREATED)))  AS DiffDate 
    FROM TICKETS A
        group by ticket_id
```

Come to think of it, I now think this could be a duplicate of

[Difference between dates in two consecutive rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12458847/difference-between-dates-in-two-consecutive-rows)

Can you try the query there...

SELECT ticketid, extract(epoch from tdiff) FROM (
  SELECT
      ticketid,
      ticketdate - lag(ticketdate) OVER (PARTITION BY ticketid ORDER BY ticketdate) AS tdiff,
      dense_rank() OVER (PARTITION BY ticketid ORDER BY ticketdate) AS rank
  FROM Table1
  ORDER BY ticketid) x
WHERE rank = 2;

and fiddle at

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/0e213/1

Comment: this is great start, but i need that n-1 factor instead of min and max with same ticket_id since sometimes there is 10-20 answers so it is automatically more than 10 days

Comment: The second query, even though by the looks of it looks to take difference between max and max, it takes the max and compares it to the second max, so that should solve your issue, let me know if my understanding is wrong or if the query does not produce that result

Comment: ok after your edit, do you want to find the delay in responses, so in the same ticket if there are 4 replies, gap between each of them?

Comment: i need only check between 2 next so if id is 1 2 3 4
i need check 1-2 2-3 3-4

Comment: I understand, let me modify the query

Comment: just found a link, I will add it to my answer

Answer (score 0):

Something *like* that might do the trick:

```
select ticket_id, min(a.time_created), max(b.time_created),
       TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR,min(a.time_created), max(b.time_created))
  from tbl AS a JOIN tbl AS b USING(ticket_id)
  where a.time_created < (b.time_created - INTERVAL 1 DAY)
  group by(a.ticket_id);
```

Producing:

```
+------------+--------------------------------+--------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------+
| TICKET_ID  |      MIN(A.TIME_CREATED)       |      MAX(B.TIME_CREATED)       | TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR,MIN(A.TIME_CREATED), MAX(B.TIME_CREATED)) |
+------------+--------------------------------+--------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------+
|         1  | August, 17 2013 12:00:00+0000  | August, 19 2013 12:11:00+0000  |                                                           48 |
+------------+--------------------------------+--------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------+
```

See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4af76e/7

Please note I used [`TIMESTAMPDIFF`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff) here, requesting a result in `HOUR`. Not knowing your domain specifications, I don't used [`TIMEDIFF`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timediff) here because of the limited range of [`TIME`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/time.html) values ( ≈ 34 days ).

Answer (score 0):

To get the difference you need the equivalent of the `lag()` function, which MySQL does not support.  You can get the same effect with a correlated subquery:

```
select ticket_id, timediff(nextTimeCreated, time_created)
from (select t.*,
             (select time_created
              from t t2
              where t2.ticket_id = t.ticket_id and
                    t2.time_created > t.time_created
             ) as nextTimeCreated
      from t
     ) t
where nextTimeCreated > time_created + interval 1 day;
```